# Postfix wrong sender email

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp, email-server

Hello my domain is example.com but when i use the mail command it sends the email with root@mail.example.com

What did i missconfigure?

Command im sending:

```
echo "Test" | mail -s "Test" my@email.com
```

The from header is `<root@mail.example.com>`

but i want `<root@example.com>`

Here is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2


# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = nasirmail.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, nasirmail.com, mail.nasirmail.com, localhost.nasirmail.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with postfix. The sender is specified by the client by default, and not touched by the mail server.

You can specify the sender with `mail` in the following way:

```
mail -a FROM:user@example.com recipient@example.com
```

Alternatively, use a more full-featured mail client, such as alpine, where you can configure this easily in a menu-driven configuration system.

Comment: The thing is alpine does not support catchall & that's what i need. Is there not a possibility to change it to default so it sends as user@example.com ?

Comment: Alpine has absolutely nothing to do with catch all; that's a server feature. Regarding sending: as I've written it's by default specified by the client, and the server does not rewrite this. Postfix *does* [support rewrite of addresses](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html), but it's probably better to let the client specify this.